# Regex Group Name prefix multiple options

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm performing regex extraction for parsing logs for our SIEM. I'm working with PCRE2.
In those logs, I have this problem: I have to extract a field that can be preceded by multiple options and I want use only one group name.

Let me be clearer with an example.

The SSH connection can appear in our log with this form:

```
UserType=SSH,
```

And I know that a simple regex expression to catch this is:

```
UserType=(?<app>.*?),
```

But, at the same time, SSH can appear with another "prefix":

```
ACCESS TYPE:SSH;
```

that can be captured with:

```
ACCESS\sTYPE:(?<app>.*?);
```

Now, because the logical field is the same (SSH protocol) and I want map it in every case under group name "app", is there a way to put the previous values in OR and use the same group name?

The desiderd final result is something like:

```
(UserType=) OR (ACCESS TYPE:) <field_value_here>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:UserType=|ACCESS\sTYPE:)(?<app>[^,;]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EMsgtC/1). *Details*:

- `(?:UserType=|ACCESS\sTYPE:)` - either `UserType=` or `ACCESS` + whitespace + `TYPE:`
- `(?<app>[^,;]+)` - Group "app": one or more chars other than `,` and `;`.